# High Chart - stacked Bar Dynamic grouping

Tags: css

I need to crated a stacked bar chart with dynamic series.

**Example:**

Year    Name    Val

2010    Col1    100

2010    Col2    200

2011    Col1    100

2011    Col2    200

2012    Col1    100

2012    Col2    200

2012    Col3    500

Here 2012 has one more Series col3 (Which is dynamic and I do not know at design time)

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your data.

I have kept 0 to hide series.

```
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 0]
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [1, 2, 3, 0, 1]
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [0, 4, 4, 2, 5]
    }]
```

[See original demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/uyXn6/)

[Here is edited demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/uyXn6/3/)